# Error posting date to HubSpot API

Tags: c#, hubspot, hubspot-crm

I am trying to post a date field to the HubSpot contact API, however, I am getting errors stating a UTC date is not midnight.

> "1505779200 is at 10:16:19.200 UTC, not midnight!"

However, if you use this [tool](https://www.epochconverter.com/), and enter that value you will see that the value is midnight.

The c# code I use to do the conversion is:

```
 public static double DateTimeToUTC(System.DateTime dateTime)
 {
        dateTime = System.DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var utcValue = ((DateTimeOffset) dateTime).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
        return utcValue;
 }
```

Can anyone help?

Cheers

KH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried posting the UNIX time in milliseconds (rather than seconds)? [HubSpot FAQ here](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/faq/how-should-timestamps-be-formatted-for-hubspots-apis)

> HubSpot API endpoints accept UNIX formatted timestamps in **milliseconds**. ...
>
> ...
>
> *Date/Datetime properties in HubSpot Contacts*
>
> Date properties will only store the date, and must be set to midnight UTC for the date you want.  For example, May 1 2015 would be 1430438400000 (01 May 2015 00:00:00 UTC). If you try to set a value that is not midnight UTC, you will receive an error.

Try switching to `.toUnixTimeMilliseconds()` and give it a whirl! ([MSDN Ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimemilliseconds(v=vs.110).aspx))

```
public static double DateTimeToUTC(System.DateTime dateTime)
{
    dateTime = System.DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    var utcValue = ((DateTimeOffset) dateTime).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
    return utcValue;
}
```